# POS For .NET: Failed to set property properties of PosPrinter

Tags: .net, point-of-sale, opos

I can't set properties of PosPritnter class. For example PageModeStation, PageModeVerticalPosition, PageModePrintArea etc.

```
PosPrinter posPrinter = (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(posPrinterInfo);
posPrinter.Open();
posPrinter.Claim(1000);
posPrinter.DeviceEnabled = true;
posPrinter.PageModeVerticalPosition = 10; //<--- Exception thrown: Failed to set property PageModeVerticalPosition
```

Exception details:

```
    Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException was unhandled
    Message="Failed to set property PageModeVerticalPosition."
    Source="Microsoft.PointOfService"
    ErrorCodeExtended=0
    StackTrace:
           at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyProxy.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
           at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyPosPrinter.set_PageModeVerticalPosition(Int32 value)
       ....
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the printer supports it, you probably need to:
1 - Enable page mode

```
posPrinter.PageModePrint(PageModePrintControl.PageMode);
```

2 - Define the print area.

```
posPrinter.PageModePrintArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, posPrinter.PageModeArea.X, posPrinter.PageModeArea.Y);
```

Before attempting to set that property.

Comment: Can you please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408057/pos-for-net-print-formatting-cant-use-escape-character-char27#comment16677149_12408057  I can't seem to get the Microsoft POSPrinter Simulator to have any sort of formatting (bold, text alignment, etc). Doesn't work on my actual pos printer either.