# POS for .Net print formatting - can't use escape character (char)27

Tags: c#, printing, ascii, pos-for-.net

I figured out how to print basic text to our POS printer, but I can't figure out how to get the escape characters to work (for bold, text alignment, etc). For now I'm just testing with the Microsoft PosPrinter Simulator.

Here's what I'm trying

```
_printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, (char)27 + "|bC" + printText + (char)13 + (char)10);
```

I'd expect that to print my `printText` in bold followed by a line break. When I take out `(char)27 + "|bC"` then it works fine.

The [documentation for the escape codes is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.pointofservice.posprinter.aspx)

The error I get is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.PointOfService.ControlBase.dll Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

I tried a bunch of variations but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**Edit**. Here's the stack trace..

```
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulatorWindow.ProcessEscapes(String str)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulatorWindow.DisplayText(String str)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.DeviceSimulators.PosPrinterSimulator.PrintNormalImpl(PrinterStation station, PrinterState printerState, String data)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.BaseServiceObjects.PosPrinterBase.OutputRequestHandler(OutputRequest Request)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Internal.PosCommonInternal.ProcessOutputRequest(OutputRequest request, Boolean asyncOperation)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.BaseServiceObjects.PosPrinterBase.ProcessRequest(PrintOperation operation)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.BaseServiceObjects.PosPrinterBase.PrintNormal(PrinterStation station, String data)
   at MyProjectNamespace) in MyFile.cs:line 74
```

Comment: What is the value of printText?

Comment: @Prescott - "Our Company" ... nothing fancy in that string.

Comment: You can try to use 'Convert.ToChar(27)' instead of (char)27

Comment: I'm not familiar, was just reading the documentation, seems the string that ends the escape code must start with a capital 'The escape sequence is stopped by an uppercase alphabetic character.' Just wanted to ensure that was the case

Comment: @habakuk No luck with Convert.ToChar(27). I may have to just pad my lines with spaces to get them where I want them :/

Comment: It is just a "first chance" exception, not a real one.  Debug + Exceptions, untick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi just found out this answer and this works for me. try this one.

```
string Bold = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 27, (byte)'|', (byte)'b', (byte)'C' });
```

or  You can simply declare this:

```
 string ESC = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] {27});
```

then use it in your format or text like this:

ESC + "|cA" -- this is for center.
 ESC + "|bC"  -- for bold.

ESC + "|bC" + "hello world" -- this will bold the string.

Comment: I switched jobs since I posted this question so I don't have the opportunity to test it out, but I will mark it as the answer

Comment: How do you undo [disable] the bold to print something non bold?

Comment: Just wanted to say that this solution worked for me, using an HP printer and JavaPos.


Previously I had the following escape sequence in my string `\\u001B|bC` that I would send straight to the printer. It was working, but it suddenly stopped - not sure how - but it's worth trying this too, if the above doesn't work for you.


For anybody coming here using Javascript, the above solution would look like `String.fromCharCode(27) + "|bC"` and you can stop bolding by then adding `String.fromCharCode(27) + "|N"`

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to escape the string like this:

```
_printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\x1B|bCYour Bold line\r\n");
```

Maybe you can still use it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your printer supports Bold, Italic etc? i.e.

```
if (_printer.CapRecBold)
   // printer supports bold

if (_printer.CapRecItalic)
   // printer supports italic
```

Answer (score 1):

From my testing I think the printer simulator will not accept the ESC character.

I create the text to send to the printer using a number of constant substitutes like:

```
      string escAlignCenter = String.Format("{0}|cA", ((char)27));
      string escAlignRight = String.Format("{0}|rA", ((char)27));
      string escBoldOn = String.Format("{0}|bC", ((char)27));
      string escNewLine = String.Format("{0}|1lF", ((char)27));
      string escPaperCut = String.Format("{0}|75P", ((char)27));
      string escReset = String.Format("{0}|N", ((char)27));
      string escUnderlineOn = String.Format("{0}|uC", ((char)27));
```

so I might send the following to the printer:

```
String.Format("{0}Hellow world!", escAlignCenter)"
```

To avoid getting the error when using the printer simulator I need to do the following

```
      if(useSimulator)
      {
        string xxx = String.Format("{0}", ((char)27));
        string testString = testPrint.ToString();
        testString = testString.Replace(xxx, "\\");
        logger.Debug("text to print is [{0}]", testString);
        posPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, testString); 
      }
      else
        posPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, testPrint.ToString());
```

That removes the error however the text printed to the simulator includes all the ESC formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up determining how many characters could be printed per line and created some alignment functions. At this point I think there is nothing built-in to POS for .Net.

Still can't figure out bold, italics, etc. formatting.

Comment: I also did the same thing because I got tired of trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Androidz answer is correct. Also you can do some thing like below.

Assume you want to print bold.

```
string text = "ESC|bC" + "BOLD Text";
// Now replace ESC as below.
string textToPrint = text.Replace("ESC", ((char)27).ToString());
```

That's it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the above question. But if you like to see the sample project for POS printer, you can follow this this github project, added by me.
https://github.com/harshanpremarathna/pos-print

Answer (score 0):

This string worked for me ["\u001B"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/epson-esc-pos-with-formatting)